# Langchain support for h2ogpt at runtime

Tags: python, langchain, large-language-model, llama, h2ogpt

Greeting.
I am using h2ogpt with LLM for making answers in local mode and LLama2 mdoel is working well.
For now the issue is supporting langchain at runtime. I am using following command line to load custom documents at the begining of h2ogpthttps://github.com/h2oai/h2ogpt.

```
python generate.py --base_model='llama' --prompt_type=llama2 --score_model=None --langchain_mode='UserData' --user_path=user_path --model_path_llama=f:\temp\Conda\llama-2-7b-chat.ggmlv3.q8_0.bin --max_seq_len=4096 --cli=True
```

If I put custom documents in user_path directory, it works well and I can make question regarding custom documents and get correct answers.
The problem is how I can load other documents without restarting the h2ogpt because its loading takes a bit long time even on GPU machine.
If built-in h2ogpt script does not support this functioning, other custom scripts will be welcome.
I am beginner on h2ogpt and I will appreciate for reading.
Thanks.

I have tried passing parameters to solve this problem so it seems to require custom h2ogpt script, not generate.py.